# What does "commuting with the Hamiltonian" mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, commutator, observables

In quantum mechanics an observable or an attribute to a particle (like spin) is conserved if and only if it commutes with the Hamiltonian. What does this mean? What observables do not commute with the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 6):

Apart from two other answers, consider the Heisenberg picture and the equation of motion where its written as

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = - \frac{i}{\hbar} [A , H]$$

So if an operator commutes with the Hamiltonian, from the above equation its obvious that

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 0$$

So the quantity attributed to $A$ is conserved.

Answer (score 5):

Two operators $A$ and $B$ *commute* if (and only if) their *commutator* $[A,B]$ vanishes
\begin{equation}
[A,B] \equiv AB - BA = 0 \implies A,B\ {\rm commute}
\end{equation}
Consider a Hamiltonian operator for a single particle in 1 dimension
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)
\end{equation}
where $x$ the *position operator*, $p$ is the *momentum operator*, and $m$ is the mass of the particle (which is just a number).

$x$ and $p$ have a commutator
\begin{equation}
[x,p]=i\hbar
\end{equation}
Using this, it is easy to see that $[H,x]\neq 0$, and $[H,p]\neq 0$ unless $V(x)$ is a constant. Therefore, in general, neither the position nor the momentum are conserved. The momentum is conserved only if the potential is constant.

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics, observables are represented by Hermitian operators. Mathematically, two operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ commute if $$\tag 1 [ \hat A, \hat B]=\hat A \hat B- \hat B \hat A = 0$$

Hermitian operators which satisfy (1) are also called *compatible observables* meaning that both can be measured *simultaneously*.

Hermitian operators which do not commute and do not satisy (1) are called incompatible observables, and a good example of this in quantum mechanics are [the canonical commutation relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation).

**Now:**

Operators or observables that commute with the Hamiltonian of the system are **conserved quantities**, e.g. angular momentum or spin. This means that these quantities do not change with time. Those that do not commute with the Hamiltonian, are not conserved quantities.

To summarise, if $\hat H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system then if

$$[\hat H, \hat O] = 0$$ then $\hat O$ is conserved and $$\frac{d \hat O}{dt}=0$$ but if
$$[\hat H, \hat O] \ne 0$$ then $\hat O$ is *not* conserved and $$\frac{d \hat O}{dt} \ne 0$$

Commutation relations also do not depend on our choice of basis meaning they work just as well in coordinate space as they do in momentum space. This is a [powerful result used in quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space).

Answer (score 0):

Most observables do not commute with the Hamiltonian:
$$
[\hat A,\hat H]\equiv \hat A\hat H-\hat H\hat A\ne 0\, .
$$

For instance, if the potential is not constant, it will not in general commute with $\hat H$; neither will the kinetic energy operator for that matter.

Since for the simplest operators $[\hat A,\hat B]=i\hbar\widehat{\{A,B\}}$, where $\{A,B\}$ is the classical Poisson bracket, the statement that two operators commute is the quantum version of the statement that two classical quantities Poisson-commute, and the statement that an operator is conserved if it commutes with $\hat H$ is the quantum version of the well-known statement that a classical quantity will be conserved when it Poisson-commutes with $H$.